# Creating a new object equal

Tags: c#

I can't remember term that was used for this:

I have a class:

```
public class Region
{
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And when i do this:

```
Region a = new Region();
Region b = new Region();
b=a;
b.id = 1;
```

And the `a.id` value changes - how do I prevent this? And what was the term for this?

Comment: Are you thinking of the term reference type?

Comment: Don't set `b`'s reference equal to `a`? Why are you doing that anyway?

Comment: You'll have to copy the property values. `ICloneable` is meant for this behaviour.

Comment: Use a `struct` instead.

Comment: because this class is just for example. in my real class there are more data, and i need to modify data

Comment: or you can create [`Copy Constructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173116(v=vs.80).aspx) and write smth like this: `Region b = new Region(a);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Region` is a reference type, rather than a value type, so when you do

```
b = a;
```

you are copying the reference a to the reference b, and so a and b are pointing to the same data.

If you don't want that, either make `Region` a `struct` (which is a value type but this means that it gets copied all over the place when you use it as a parameter or when you assign it to a variable), or implement a `Clone()` method which produces a copy:

```
public Region Clone()
{
    var result = new Region();
    result.Id = this.Id;
    result.Name = this.Name;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deep copy the value type properties:

```
Region a = new Region();
Region b = new Region();
b = new Region { id = a.id, name = a.name };
b.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `a.id` changes because `b` references to `a`. You can to manually set the value of the property from `a` or use [`Value Injecter`](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/).

[Here's an example using Value Injecter.](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=step%20by%20step%20explanation&referringTitle=Home) *Useful when you have tons of properties.*

```
Region a = new Region();
Region b = new Region();
b.InjectFrom(a);
b.id = 1;
```